# Como criar uma função jQuery para puxar o menu pra cima?

Tags: jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de usar jQuery para subir e descer este menu. Podem me ajudar? O resultado final deve ser este ... Eu comecei o código mas não sei mais como continuar.

```
$("#esconder_menu").on("click", function(){
     // #header-main <---- esse é o id do menu a subir.
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basta diminuir o `height` do elemento. Se quiser escondê-lo completamente defina `0`, senão deixe uns 10 ou 15 `px`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não deu muitos detalhes, mas se só estiver faltando a animação de recolher o menu, o [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) deve resolver:

```
$("#esconder_menu").on("click", function(){
     $('#header-main').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: O SlideUp some totalmente com o bloco, não gostaria que sumisse, simplesmente subisse até a altura da segunda figura.

Comment: Sem conhecer o HTML desse trecho não dá pra responder mais que isso...

Comment: Basicamente você precisa aplicar o `slideUp` só na parte que é pra sumir. Se ela não está separada no seu HTML, embrulhe em uma div.